# How to use Cricket API for mvc 5 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to implement `Cricket API` in our `MVC` project I have found `API` from this website   http://www.cricapi.com/how-to-use.aspx 
 But I don't know how to implement in the `MVC` project. if someone know other way to implement `Cricket API` in `MVC` Project to tell us

Comment: Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/webapi/consuming-web-api-in-dotnet-using-httpclient)

Answer (score 0):

U can consume a api into ur action by

```
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(API_URL);
            //HTTP GET
            var responseTask = client.GetAsync();
            responseTask.Wait();

            var result = responseTask.Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Model>();
                readTask.Wait();

                var data = readTask.Result;

            }
        }
```

though i would suggest u to use jquery or some js frameworks like angular, react 
to achieve whatever you want to.